# How to use advanced probability theory to explain "Independent" of two randan variable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

We know from elementary probability theory, two random variable $X,Y$ are called independent if $F_X(x)F_Y(y)=F_{XY}(x,y).$ where the notation are their cdf. But in measure space, assume $X,Y$ $\sim$ $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{P}).$ If we take $\Omega=[0,1],$ suppose $w_1\in \Omega=[0,1]$ and $X(w_1)=1$, how to explain $Y$ in this $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{P})$ in order to make $X$ and $Y$ independent? Can you give me an example or some related theorems to help me deeply understand this? Thank you so much!

Comment: The situation is exactly the same as it is in elementary probability theory, it's just that now the CDF is constructed through the probability measure $P$. One way to actually *construct* independent variables explicitly is to consider something like $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)=[0,1]^2$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue measure. Then $X(\omega)=\omega_1$ (i.e. the first component of the vector $\omega$),$Y(\omega)=\omega_2$ are two independent uniform (0,1) variables.

Comment: @Gatsby: Why can't you applied the independence definition using CDFs? Is the only thing you know about $X$ and $Y$, that $X(w_1) = 1$ for a $w_1$?

Comment: I had written this for random vectors.. Maybe it is helpful, maybe not... Not sure if it is correct...
$\{X_t\in B_t\}:=\{\omega\in \Omega\colon X_t(\omega)\in B_t\}\\
{P}(\bigcap_{j=0}^{n} \{X_j\in B_j\}) =\prod_{j=0}^{n}{P}(\{X_j\in B_j\}) \quad \forall B_0,\ldots,B_n \in \mathcal{B}({R})$

Comment: $X(w_1)=1$ doesn't tell you anything at all, unless $\mathcal P(w_1)>0$.

Comment: @lan So you mean in this  case, $X$ and $Y$ has different $\Omega$?

Comment: @user251257 I just made an example. I just want to find ties between $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and elementary probability theories

Comment: @Emil yeah, I think you are correct. But I want to find some relations between two independent randam variables.

Comment: Are you missing the connection $F(x) = \mathcal P(\{ \omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \le x \})$?

Comment: @Gatsby In my example $X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same probability space. It can be inconvenient to insist that this space be just $[0,1]$, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer from a general measure-theoretic point of view.

If you have real-valued random variables $X,Y$ on $\Omega$, you can use them to obtain two (probability) measures on ${\bf R}$, namely $X[\mathcal P]$ and $Y[\mathcal P]$. At the same time, $(X,Y)$ is a ${\bf R}^2$-valued random variable on $\Omega$, which gives us a (probability) measure $(X,Y)[\mathcal P]$ on ${\bf R}^2$.

We say that $X,Y$ are independent if $(X,Y)[\mathcal P]=X[\mathcal P]\otimes Y[\mathcal P]$, or in other words, $(X,Y)[\mathcal P]$ is the product measure of $X[\mathcal P]$ and $Y[\mathcal P]$. By definition, it means that for any intervals $I,J\subseteq {\bf R}$ you have
$$
\mathcal P((X,Y)^{-1}[I\times J])=\mathcal P(X^{-1}[I])\cdot \mathcal P(Y^{-1}[J])
$$
Since $(X,Y)^{-1}[I\times J]=X^{-1}[I]\cap Y^{-1}[J]$, this is equivalent to saying that for any intervals $I,J$ you have
$$
\mathcal P(X\in I\land Y\in J)= \mathcal P(X\in I)\cdot \mathcal P(Y\in J).
$$
I.e. the events $X\in I$ and $Y\in J$ are independent. It is easy to see that you can take half-lines instead of intervals here, so in fact this is equivalent to saying that for any real numbers $a,b$ the events $X\leq a$ and $Y\leq b$ are independent, which is exactly the statement you have given.

The first definition generalises immediately to random variables taking value in an arbitrary measure space (except then you may have no notion of a cumulative distribution function, or you may have to consider more complicated sets than just intervals), and in fact measurable functions on any measure space. It also works more or less the same for more than two variables (even infinitely many).